# WebGL context Lost on Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

My project is loading around 1 GB models using SVF1 urns on the Forge viewer. After a while I programmatically navigate to different positions on the viewer, I get this error. The app can also load other urns before which I do a viewer.finish(). But the error keeps re-occurring after some time in both Chrome and Firefox. Is there a way to handle this without reloading the viewer?

Error: [ErrorSnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIpoJ.png)

I would have to load much larger files, about 2GB or more going forward.

This is the navigation code:

```
SetNavigation(x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2) {
      this.viewer.navigation.setView({ x: x1, y: y1, z: z1 }, { x: x2, y: y2, z: z2 });
      this.viewer.navigation.toPerspective();
      this.viewer.navigation.setVerticalFov(75, true);
      this.viewer.getCamera().perspectiveCamera.zoom=0.5;
      this.viewer.navigation.setIsLocked(true);
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("toolbar-bimWalkTool")).click();
};
```

This is what I do before loading a different SVF1 urn:

```
  this.viewer.finish();
  this.viewer = null;
  Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
```

Comment: Would you kindly share the error message or screenshot if possible for more clarification?

Comment: @Arrotech have attached error screenshot on the question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to **finish** the viewer for each model, just load the new model and the viewer takes care of memory cleanup.

To load a new model, just call **.load** again.